# In the Symbology Properties of an ArcGIS layer, why is the count sometimes not shown?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, symbology

Sometimes the count column does populate for me, but most times it does not seem to. I haven't been able to figure out a rhyme or reason to it. There is no definition query or anything out of the ordinary. Is this a bug or is there something you can do to make sure that field is populated?

I am running ArcView 10 on Windows 7 x64.

[image: screencapture of symbology window]

Comment: How many records are in the attribute table?

Comment: 465 records in there.

Comment: Hmm... it used to be (9.x) that when there were more than 20k records, not all were read and you would get this kind of behavior.  Perhaps your data are accessed over a slow network connection?

Comment: B, Does it have anything to do with the data not being indexed? Are you working with SHP, or DB? I've noticed this to, but never had the need to get it worked out

Comment: Your specific question is "why" - I'm not sure about the exact conditions which cause this. But in case you're not aware of this, the workaround is to click on the Count heading, which will force ArcMap to count the features.

Comment: @Stephen That answers the question ("is there something you can do?").  Consider pasting it into a reply.

Comment: Good call Jason @Jmwgeospatial , it was a SHP, and I tried it again with a GDB feature and it populated - but I'm not sure that's exactly it. I then added the same SHP into a blank map and the count came up. Not sure why it didn't come up in my populated MXD. The workaround works though - clicking on the Count heading.  And I wouldn't rule out a slow network connection @whuber, This morning it works (3 people in the office on the network), yesterday midday it doesn't.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but I've noticed losing the Count numbers when individual items in the legend are grouped. Did not know about clicking on the County heading to refresh - thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The workaround is to click on the Count heading, which will force ArcMap to count the features.

As an aside, this can be the fastest way to view the frequency distribution of your data. Rather than using the > Table > Summarize option, just create a Unique Values symbology using the field you're interested in, view the Count, then hit Cancel so you don't actually apply the symbology.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround sometimes doesn't work after you add values and group categories. You need to click ok, then go back into the Layer Properties and then ArcMap will now let you calculate the counts by clicking on the Count heading.